# Encode jpeg to H264 stream on Android (ffmpeg)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, jpeg, h.264, encode

I have a bunch of jpeg images representing a video.
I need to encode the images in H264 format so I can stream it to a server (from android device).
I understand this can be done using ffmpeg library. I compiled ffmpeg to a .so file and now I'm trying to find out what methods to use and how...

Anyone know how can I convert jpeg into H264 stream on Android using ffmpeg?
Any sample code will be appreciated :)

Thanks!
PB

Comment: Hi. Did you succeed? I could get to convert images to MPEG from linux, but when copy the same code to JNI in Android (yes I could build libffmpeg.so) I get a green video. I will try with H264.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg

ProjectTest in this project has android code that creates mp4 from collection of jpg's (video) and an mp3 (audio)

This project is forked from another project on git ..
 you can build it on linux following the instructions

Comment: http://rowntreerob.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/ffmpeg-on-android-adding-vmware-and-ubuntu-to-best-practice/
http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

links to help with builds

Comment: I was able to use the roman10.net guide to compile ffmpeg.
The problem is that the android-ffmpeg project builds its own library containing the ffmpeg. I can't compile this lib.
Have you succeeded compiling it yourself?

Comment: I could not found the methods for "videokit" (initialize, encode, etc).

Comment: yes. i can make a movie ( mp4, webm ) on the phone ( android 4.0.4 ) with jpg inputs ( static images ).

Comment: The general method is creating a shared lib from a collection of static libs and then including the libs in the apk via the use of $NDK/build-ndk and the Android.mk files that you create following the patterns ikn the samples in the NDK/samples directory.

Comment: look at the git! hotovy forked halfninja. The "videokit" that you ask about is in halfninja. https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/tree/master/Project/jni

Comment: the respective projects use slightly diff methods of linking the shared libs and using those in the jni code. you are going to have to wade into the details and to learn the specifics used in the respective "Android.mk" files from these 2 git projects.

Comment: @RobertRowntree have you gotten the ffmpeg command to merge video from images to work reliably on any test devices?  Currently I have an issue where ffmpeg always prints a "No such file or directory" error on all devices except the Galaxy Nexus (on which it works!)

Comment: on a galaxy nexus running 4.0.4, i can create an mp4 from slides using "r%02d.jpg" type input expression getting image files from  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES directory . Thats all ive tested

Comment: I compiled ffmpeg and found some samples on how to create the stream. The problem is that I fail to encode jpeg images to H264. Dummy images using YCbCr are no problem. Can anyone share the "Encode" method they use to encode an image to H264? (no command line)

Comment: BTW, from what I understand halfninga/jhotovy are only sending args to ffmpeg main. They do not call the encode methods....

Answer (score 0):

I use the modified script to compile ffmpeg with android NDK r8 and ffmpeg 0.1.11.

```
#!/bin/bash

######################################################
# FFmpeg builds script for Android+ARM platform
#
# This script is released under term of 
#   CDDL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/cddl1) 
# Wrote by pinxue (~@gmail.com) from RockPlayer.com
#                                   2010-8 ~ 2011-4
# Modified by Jacx Wang jacxwang(@)gmail.com 2012-07
######################################################

NDK=/Users/jacxwang/app/android-ndk-r8
PLATFORM=/Users/jacxwang/app/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
PREBUILT=/Users/jacxwang/app/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86


function build_one
{

./configure --target-os=linux \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-cross-compile \
--extra-libs="-lgcc" \
--arch=arm \
--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
--sysroot=$PLATFORM \
--extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
--enable-parsers \
--enable-encoders  \
--enable-decoders \
--enable-muxers \
--enable-demuxers \
--enable-swscale  \
--disable-ffplay \
--enable-ffprobe \
--enable-ffserver \
--enable-network \
--enable-indevs \
--disable-bsfs \
--disable-filters \
--enable-protocols  \
--enable-asm \
--enable-gpl \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG


#make clean
make  -j3 install

$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o

$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a 

}

#arm v6
CPU=armv6
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#build_one

#arm v7vfpv3
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one

#arm v7vfp
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU "
PREFIX=./android/$CPU-vfp
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one

#arm v6+vfp
CPU=armv6
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-DCMP_HAVE_VFP -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -marm -march=$CPU"
PREFIX=./android/${CPU}-vfp 
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
build_one
```